# Get a message if the value put in a column is not unique

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to receive a message in case I put a value that already exists in a column, I've found a way to filter distinct records but nothing that would alert me as soon as I add the new element.

Comment: @pnuts, that seems worthy of an answer.

Comment: @pnuts, seems to me like it fits.

Comment: @pnuts, what a deal. Who can resist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pnuts commented you can use Data Validation and a formula that returns TRUE only when there's one instance of the value in the column. You could use a `MATCH` formula like he showed, or this `COUNTIF` formula. This addresses the issue pnuts mentioned of checking the whole column:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=1
```

I entered this under Custom in the Data Validation dialog:

[image]

When the user tries to enter the number a second time, they see this:

[image]

Comment: The function COUNTIF is giving me an error, I've found the sintax and it's correct, so  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7pbt9f
It gives me this error, what am I doing wrong?
(what it says in english is that the formula contains an error)

Comment: Perhaps your country's version of Excel uses `;` as a formula delimiter? (I'm not sure if that's covered by your comment above that the syntax is correct). So, does `=COUNTIF(A:A;A2)=1` work? Can you try this, or any, `COUNTIF` formula just in a worksheet cell and get it to work?

Comment: @pnuts I had to use the name of the function in my language "CONTA.SE" and the ";" as separator. I don't like this aspect of excel.. Anyway now it works perfectly thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Sorry I've found out that if I copy paste the text, then the validation doesn't work. Is there a workaround?

Comment: That is a hard issue. Do a search for "excel prevent paste over validation" and you might find something that works for you.